# How to implement the Control center interactive dismiss animation

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently trying to replicate the dismiss interaction of the iOS Control Panel. So far I've been only able to dismiss the view by swiping down. I'm not able to replicate that same elasticity when swiping upwards and the smooth transition when swiping down after swiping up or generally just playing with the view.

Here is my handlePan handler inside the view I'm trying to dismiss:

```
func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self)

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:

        self._displayPosition = self.frame
        self._dismissAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.75, curve: .easeOut)

        self._dismissAnimator.pauseAnimation()
    case .changed:
        if translation.y < 0 {
            self._dismissAnimator.addAnimations {
                self.frame = self._displayPosition.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -20)
            }
            self._dismissAnimator.fractionComplete = -translation.y*0.10/20
        } else {
            self._dismissAnimator.addAnimations {
                self.frame = self._displayPosition.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self._offsetFromScreenBottom)
            }
            self._dismissAnimator.fractionComplete = translation.y / self._offsetFromScreenBottom
        }

    case .ended:
        if self.frame.origin.y < self._displayPosition.origin.y {
            self._dismissAnimator.stopAnimation(true)
            self._dismissAnimator.addAnimations {
                self.frame = self._displayPosition
            }
            self._dismissAnimator.startAnimation()
        } else {
            self._dismissAnimator.continueAnimation(withTimingParameters: nil, durationFactor: 0)
        }
    default:
        self._dismissAnimator.finishAnimation(at: .start)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For tips on writing great questions visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you have any questions about the site, you can visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) or visit [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)